# How to Display the level of variable?

Tags: r

I want to display the levels in variable.

My question is:

> Create a vector variable with the values "yes", "no", "yes", "maybe".
> Display the levels in this variable.

What I have tried:

```
vector <- factor(c("yes","no","yes","maybe"));
print(nlevels(vector))
```

The output is

```
[1] 3
```

Is this correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: If you want to print levels, try `levels` not `nlevels`.

Comment: Use print.factor(vector) to pretty print vector.

Comment: You do not need `;` if two separete code pieces are in separete rows. Just use it if two code piceces are in one line

Answer (score 0):

`nlevels` gives you number of level in the factor, which in your case is 3

if you want to print all levels within the factor use `level(vector)`